# Create GoogleMap Object in other file Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have problem with creating GoogleMap object in JavaScrpit using Cordova/PhoneGap.
I have 2 JavaScript files. index.js (main file) and Map.js, where I'm creating GoogleMap Object.

In Map.js i have this:

```
    var Map = {
        /*Google Map Object*/
var googleMap:null,
/*Array of Waypoints.Start Waypoint is on 0 index, last on last*/
var waypointsArray = [],
/**/
        onSuccessLoad : function(position) {
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            var mapOptions = {
                center : latLong,
                zoom : 3,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
                    mapOptions);
            //addWaypoint(latLong,'img/startNode.png');

        },

}
```

in index.js :

```
var app = {
    watchID : null,
    // Application Constructor
    initialize : function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents : function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady : function() {
        // app.receivedEvent('deviceready');


        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(Map.onSuccessLoad,
                GPSErrorHandler.checkGPSConnection);
    },

};

app.initialize();
```

and my **index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
<meta name="viewport"
    content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<title>Working Google Maps</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ErrorHandlers/GPSErrorHandler.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ErrorHandlers/InternetErrorHandler.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Map.js"></script>

    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKey">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I compile it to Android using **phonegap compile android** the APK creates,but when I install the apk on Android device there is nothing on screen. But when I have all code in one file, without classes and Map var it was working.... so what is wrong with my code?

GoogleApi key is good I have changed it to paste code here, so it's not a problem.

Comment: Please remove the var keyword in googleMap, and waypointsArray You are using the Map object with in that you need to add the properties(name and value pair) so just put googleMap:null, waypointsArray: [], and check.

Comment: I have changed everything in the way you describe it. It worked. I have never use JavaScript.. and Its difficult to me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug certificate is different from your production certificate. You need to add both to your Google Maps key entry in your API console as seaparate row - each with the same packageId, but naturally different SHA1 hash.

Since your are using javascript its better to use Google maps v3 api

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

Comment: I sad that that key isn't the problem in here. When I have map created in the **index.js** there is no problem... but I want to have it in another file

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `var` keyword in `googleMap`, and `waypointsArray` You are using the `Map` object, with in that you need to add the properties(name and value pair) so just put `googleMap:null, waypointsArray: []`, and check